# how to make a fixed menu from second screen in fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, fullpage.js

hi i am using (one page site) i need a sticky menu from the second screen, i gave it position sticky, it works if fullpage.js is disabled. If I enable fullpage, then the styles are interrupted and the menu does not work, help https://jsfiddle.net/px5mjqab /`

```
$(function(){
/* $('#fullpage').fullpage({
 autoScrolling:true,
 scrollHorizontally: true,
 sectionSelector: '.page-section'
 } */);
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a page with scroll bar in order to make the sticky element work as sticky.

To do so with fullPage.js you'll need to use the fullPage.js option `scrollBar:true` as in [this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html)